# Error when launching Kibana : cannot execute binary file - undefined error 0

Tags: kibana, elk

I'm very new to the ELK stack and was trying to add some security settings (username and password) to access Kibana following the instructions from the link below:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security

**At Step 4: Security in Kibana**, once the yml file modified, I try to launch Kibana from the terminal with the command `./bin/kibana` but it displays the following errors :

```
./bin/kibana: line 24: /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/kibana-7.6.2-linux-x86_64/bin/../node/bin/node: cannot execute binary file
./bin/kibana: line 24: /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/kibana-7.6.2-linux-x86_64/bin/../node/bin/node: Undefined error: 0
```

I think I've followed all the previous steps carefully and everything else worked so far.
I'm using a Mac and the error seems to be very basic. Any clue?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've downloaded the wrong architecture (Linux) of Kibana on your Mac.

This generally happens when the architecture is not compatible with system architecture or running a 64 bits on 32 bits machine.

**Simple solution:**

Download the mac version of Kibana from here - https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana

Once downloaded, run `./bin/kibana` in Kibana directory.

This will successfully start local server of Kibana on `localhost:5601`